# Is it possible to add two words together while counting the word frequencies? Python

Tags: python, nlp, frequency, cpu-word

```
top_N = 100

words = review_tip['user_tip'].dropna()
words = words.astype(str)
words = words.str.replace('[{}]'.format(string.punctuation), '')
words = words.str.lower().apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (stopwords)]))

# replace '|'-->' ' and drop all stopwords
words = words.str.lower().replace([r'\|', RE_stopwords], [' ', ''], regex=True).str.cat(sep=' ').split()

# generate DF out of Counter
rslt = pd.DataFrame(Counter(words).most_common(top_N),
                    columns=['Word', 'Frequency']).set_index('Word')
print(rslt)
plt.clf()
# plot
rslt.plot.bar(rot=90, figsize=(16,10), width=0.8)
plt.show()
            Frequency
Word                 
great           17069

food            16381

good            12502

service         11342

place           10841

best             9280

get              7483

love             7042

amazing          5043

try              4945

time             4810

go               4594

dont             4377
```

As you can see the words are singular which is something I can use, but is it possible to take like two words that couldve been used together a lot?

For example getting

dont go (this could be for 100 times)

instead of getting it separate

dont 100

go 100

Comment: It's possible, you just have to write code that looks for phrases like this instead of just using `x.split()` to split it up into words.

Comment: Do you have a list of these phrases that you want to treat as a single word? If not, how are you planning on finding them?

Comment: @Barmar Thats where I am stuck i was thinking if anything using n_grams was possible?

Answer (score 0):

This will generate bi-grams, is this what you are looking for:

```
bi_grams = zip(words, words[1:])
```

I generates tuples which is fine to use in the counter but you could also easily tweak the code to use `' '.join((a, b))`.